# Schengen tourist visa - Switzerland/Hungary

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, switzerland

My wife and I plan to visit a few European countries (France, Switzerland, Hungary, Czechia, and the Netherlands) and need to apply for the Schengen visa.
As we spend most nights in Switzerland, we will be applying for visa via Swiss consulate in Sydney. However, I'll be applying for a business visa since I'm attending a conference while traveling and a tourist visa for the wife.
Could someone clarify the following

1. I have the invitation letter from the conference (conference in Hungary) which I will provide as "Information on host and/or accommodation" section. But what should I put there for my wife? Do we need to put each accommodation place details under that for both me and wife?
2. We will be using Airbnb accommodations, so do we need to provide all those bookings in the online application or just the copies of booking as separate attachments?

Comment: I don't know how many days before this conference you asked this question, but Hungary shut down most public events and gatherings due to COVID-19. Keep yourself up-to-date if it's still relevant!

Comment: @Nyos Yeah now that is a concern :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had one hotel reservation, where we had both email and phone numbers. So we only put that on the online application. And all AirBnB reservations were handover to the embassy with the completed application.

Edited.
We can't proceed the online application after the accommodation section unless you put both email, telephone, first and last name of Airbnb host (hotels you don't need names). Therefore, I only put the hotel reservation under that section and didn't put any AirBnB details there. However, I submit all the Airbnb reservations when submitting the passport with other documents. Gladly receive the visa within just 2 days.